# Can I travel to Vietnam for Christmas in 2020?

Tags: indian-citizens, india, covid-19, vietnam

I am an Indian citizen and planning to travel to Vietnam during Christmas time. I did find that Vietnam is accepting online E-visa applications for Indian citizens but couldn't find any covid guidelines on the website.

Is there a travel ban in Vietnam or do we have to keep ourselves quarantine for 15 days?

Thanks

Comment: And here I am thinking "Why is it taking so many months to complete the 2-week curve flattening?"

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Off-topic, but maybe because a pandemic is not a nice and obedient computer model? Because there are factors such as weather that are still not understood? Because there are psychological and sociological factors which make it nearly impossible to maintain a constant R=1? Because there's a 2-3 week latency between measures being taken and reliable measures of their effect? Because a "flat" curve still has a terrible impact on health systems, deaths, and long-term patients? I definitely wouldn't want to be in the position of those in charge, stuck between a rock and a hard place.

Comment: @jcaron You're right, it's not a computer model, I never said it was. Just because selfish leaders and their sheep decided that they're bored of the measures that **WERE** working does not validate the holiday competition to the top of the Covid charts. However, being a petulant child is more fun than being an adult though so I guess you got me on that front...

Comment: @jcaron All that could be boiled down to "people are selfish".

Comment: @MonkeyZeus The curve flattening idea works when applied over a 2-year period. Not 2-weeks. That wasn't really explained very well, but in the curve flattening scenario the epidemic still goes through the population, just at a much slower pace in order to not overwhelm the medical facilities (which comes at huge additional costs to human life). And to maybe buy time to get a vaccine. Which seems to have worked indeed...

Comment: Re, "people are selfish." Maybe so, but please don't forget that Covid-19 is not universally noxious. _Many_ of the people who are out there spreading it are completely unaware that they are infected.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Then maybe everyone should be careful, instead of just those with symptoms... which I think is what's being suggested.

Comment: @user2705196 However, if you decide to do better than flattening and continue onwards to elimination, NZ says you can do it in 2 months. (As a reminder, the old "flattening" plan was for everyone to stay home for a bit while the government set up hundreds of emergency tent hospitals, then let everyone get sick on purpose. Does that still sound like a good plan to you?)

Comment: @user253751 Sorry, I wasn't aware your government advocated for such an option. Things were different here and we'd have to start making this discussion country specific to do it justice. But it's really just a side point and not germane to the question, so I'd skip it.

Comment: @user2705196 It's not "an option the government advocated for", it's the literal meaning of "flatten the curve".

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Nope. Not going to work. Stay home.

[Vietnam suspended most inbound commercial flights on December 1](http://news.chinhphu.vn/Home/PM-decides-to-temporarily-suspend-incoming-commercial-flights/202012/42293.vgp) and imposed [other restrictions](http://news.chinhphu.vn/Home/PM-signs-new-Directive-on-Covid19-containment-measures/202012/42306.vgp) after detecting community transmission following a several month streak without new reported cases. There are some exceptions for repatriating Vietnamese citizens and for "experts" and business people, with a quarantine requirement. If you fall into those categories, you'd have a sponsor in Vietnam.

Beyond that, the government has recently imposed several such restrictions with short notice as they try to reduce cases to 0 again, so even if you do qualify for entry, I'd be reluctant to go somewhere where you risk being stuck if there are new restrictions.

Comment: This.  My Vietnamese colleagues tell me it's quite difficult even for them to return to the country, because flights are so limited.

Comment: The idea of being stuck in Vietnam looks very attractive to me right now. ;)

Answer (score 3):

The borders of VietNam are closed due to the COVID19 pandemic. Non-citizen returns are limited to diplomats and Foreigners of economic importance to VietNam, designated so by the government.

The situation is 'fluid'.

Contact the Vietnamese Embassy in India Phone: (+91 11) 26 879 868 (vnembassy-newdelhi.mofa.gov.vn).

ALWAYS REMEMBER the possession of a Visa is NOT A GUARANTEE of entry, Immigration officials at the point of entry have the power to vary or even cancel a Visa. (Common to all countries).

Quarantine is determined by the country you are travelling from. They have old Army camps  for 2-week quarantine periods. NOT NICE.

(I am a Westerner living in VietNam)